# Sending GPS latitude and longitude to database from Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

I am working on an android app that is supposed to send gps locations to mysql database using php.
I have the Set_Location class which gets the gps location of a user upon the click of a button and the BackgroundLocation class which is supposed to send these coordinates to the mysql database. I have a problem passing these values. I am using context on the BackgroundLocation class and passing the values as parameters. Here is my Set_Location class:

```
package com.example.bensonkorir.m_ulinzi;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Set_Location extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
private Button button;
private TextView textView,latitude,longitude;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set__location);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);
    locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            double lat= location.getLatitude();
            double lon= location.getLongitude();
            String type="location";
            latitude.setText(Double.toString(lat));
            longitude.setText(Double.toString(lon));
            String lat2 = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String lon2= String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            BackgroundLocation backgroundLocation = new BackgroundLocation(this);
            backgroundLocation.execute(type, lat2,lon2);


            textView.append("\n"+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    ConfigureButton();
}


private void ConfigureButton() {

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps",5000,0,locationListener);

        }
    });

}
}
```

and this is my BackgroundLocation Class:

```
package com.example.bensonkorir.m_ulinzi;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;

import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
LocationListener locationListener;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundLocation (LocationListener locationListener){  this.locationListener= locationListener;}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String Register_Url= "http://192.168.43.254/register2.php";
    String type = params[0];
    if(type.equals("location")){
        try {
            String langitude=params[1];
            String longitude=params[2];


            URL url= new URL(Register_Url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter  = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data= URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(langitude),"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(longitude),"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line;
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();;
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return  null;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder((Context) locationListener).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(" Status");
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

Kindly assist me with this or point me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: problem passing the values..ok..but what problem...

Comment: @user2450263 the gps values are obtained but the problem is saving them to the database, there is no value passed to the php script.

Comment: i'd suggest debug and check if the asynctask is receiving the lat lon values, in the asynctask you don't need to pass locationlistener. first check if the lat-long is being passed correctly so you can figure it out in terms of what is not working and from where, so you will get why is there no value passed to script. Get the precise issue, and then if you can't solve it..post it in a question with only the relevant code